# Повесить скрипт на кнопку в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, button

Как на кнопку повесить скрипт? Управление на тачскрине. Есть кнопка, при нажатии которой должна выполняться анимация, но не в любом случае, а только при нахождении персонажа от определенного объекта на определенном расстоянии.
Вот скрипт, хотя может он и не правильный:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class hand : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform player;
public Transform mushrums;

private Animator anim;
private bool pick_up;

void Start () {
anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
pick_up = false;
}
void Update () {
anim.SetBool ("pick_up", pick_up);

float dist = Vector3.Distance(player.position, mushrums.position);
Debug.Log(dist);

if (dist <= 58.5f)    
{
pick_up = true;
//здесь удаление объекта к которому
}
else
{
pick_up= false;
}
}
}
```

Но вот как его на кнопку повесить?

Comment: @alexander barakin а можно как-то вернуть ответ к этому вопросу, вчера был, а сегодня нет

Comment: напишите в [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы используете UI button в окне Inspector есть блок On Click (Button). Нажав на плюс вы должны будете повесить объект на котором присутствует ваш скрипт. После выберете вашу функцию из списка справа. Модификатор доступа у функции должен быть public.

Comment: делаю как Вы и описали, но вот что-то с выбором функции не совсем ясно, можете подсказать какую функцию выбирать в моем скрипте

Comment: @МихаилЧ Отдельно пишите функцию, которая обрабатывает действия, которые происходят при клике.. там же и проверяете , если `pick_up`, то совершаете действие... и вот эту самую свою функцию и выбераете

Comment: Для кнопки просто сделайте функцию public void `Click(){ ... }`, имя может быть произвольное, тогда указав объект на котором висит этот скрипт вы сможете найти функцию в списке для выбора.

Answer (score 2):

Если использовать чисто `touch` управление (например при клике непосредственно на предмет), то в теории должно работать следующее. В метод `Update` поместить следующий код:

```
if (Input.touches.Length > 0 && Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.touches[0].position);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, float.MaxValue) && dist <= 58.5f) {
        hit.SendMessage("OnPress" , SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
    }
}
```

При этом еще добавить обработчик `OnPress`:

```
void OnPress() {
// делать, что вздумается.. например:
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

весь код `Update`:

```
void Update () {
    anim.SetBool ("pick_up", pick_up);
    float dist = Vector3.Distance(player.position, mushrums.position);
    Debug.Log(dist);

    if (Input.touches.Length > 0 && Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.touches[0].position);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, float.MaxValue) && dist <= 58.5f) {
            hit.SendMessage("OnPress" , SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Можно попробовать другой вариант:
в `Update` код

```
foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) //Для каждого прикосновения к экрану (ибо можно положить одновременно два пальца)
{
    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) //Если фаза прикосновения "Прикоснулся" (т.е. как только тыкнул в экран)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position); //Создаем луч в точке прикосновения
        RaycastHit hit; //Регистрируем переменную, в которой будет инфа о предмете, в который мы попали
        Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit); //Выпускаем луч и записываем всю инфу в hit
        if (hit.collider == gameObject.collider && dist <= 58.5f) //Если мы попали в объект, на котором висит этот скрипт и дистанция подходящая
        {
            //Делаем с ним что-хочем прямо здесь
        }
    }
}
```

весь код `Update`:

```
void Update () {
    anim.SetBool ("pick_up", pick_up);
    float dist = Vector3.Distance(player.position, mushrums.position);
    Debug.Log(dist);

    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) //Для каждого прикосновения к экрану (ибо можно положить одновременно два пальца)
    {
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) //Если фаза прикосновения "Прикоснулся" (т.е. как только тыкнул в экран)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position); //Создаем луч в точке прикосновения
            RaycastHit hit; //Регистрируем переменную, в которой будет инфа о предмете, в который мы попали
            Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit); //Выпускаем луч и записываем всю инфу в hit
            if (hit.collider == gameObject.collider && dist <= 58.5f) //Если мы попали в объект, на котором висит этот скрипт и дистанция подходящая
            {
                //Делаем с ним что-хочем прямо здесь
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: так а как скрипт будет понимать, что нажата определенная кнопка, как  его повесить на UI button. Делаю все как написал ниже @Solvent. Но функции как таковой не выбрать. Вообще вот как скрипт должен работать: есть кнопка UI button, у которой есть разные срабатывания в зависимости от приближения к соответствующему объекту. Например мы подошли к нужному объекту. Нажали отдельную кнопку на экране. Скрипт должен проверить расстояние. Если оно подходящее, то выполнить нужную анимацию и удалить объект к которому мы подошли.

Comment: @МихаилЧ Solvent в принципе правильно написал. У меня подходит ответ чисто к `touch` управлению. Когда клик делается непосредственно на объект. В рамках `UI` можно разве что проанализировать, что объект, на который ткнули является кнопкой... и в зависимости от типа кнопки что-то делать... но это наверное лишнее... проще одно из двух: клик непосредственно на объекте или привязка функции к кнопку UI как описано в другом ответе